# Which Stargate address is shown on the Stargate plans?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

We know from the [Stargate: The Ark of Truth](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Ark_of_Truth) that the Stargate was invented by an Ancient/Alteran named [Amelius](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Amelius).

In the movie we see the schematics/plans for a device that looks like a Stargate:

[image]

The bottom-right part looks like a six symbol gate address (with some styled hyphens between). Is it a Stargate address? Or just symbols of constellations? Or anything else?

Comment: Those definitely look like symbols for a gate address, but there are not hyphens between them. The bottom row middle and right symbol do not appear to have the "hyphen" in between them.

Comment: Well, there is only one "hyphen" missing, maybe he was leaving his home planet in a hurry.

Comment: True! I am having trouble finding any symbols that match those however. The first one is very similar to Cletus and the third similar to Norma, but it would take some serious modifications to make the others look similar I think. There is a known gate network in the Milky Way, Atlantis, and Asgard. They do not seem to be Milky Way, are definitely not Atlantian, and I like to think my buddy Thor made his own gate network without help... I can't find a picture of O'niell flying through the Othala gate to make sure though...

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

We don't know

### Long answer

Before we start looking at these symbols, we need to first understand the principles that govern the symbols used on the Stargates.

1. From the [Stargate film](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2DT.png) we learn that [the symbols represent
   constellations](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Daniel_Jackson#1996) as seen from the world where the gate resides (later retconned in SG-1 so all gates use the same 38 symbols and a unique point of origin)
2. From Stargate: [Atlantis](http://blatner.com/adam/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/atlantean.jpg) we learn that [gates in different galaxies have different symbols](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/march-26-2013-you-asked-for-it-atlantis-floor-plans-the-control-room-the-zpm-room-weirs-office-the-adrift-lifeline-art-department-package/)
3. From Avalon Part 2 we learn that the [Stargates were invented by the Ancients](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Alteran_history_book) and that [the Ancients originated in a distant galaxy](http://www.kt-boundary.net/?q=content/ark-truth)

This begs the question: would the creator of the stargates use constellations from the Milky Way when designing his prototype, or would he use constellations from his home galaxy?

Using [the reference of gate symbols that we know](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Glyph#Milky_Way_glyphs), while there are several similarities, a 1:1 correspondence between these known Milky Way symbols and the glyphs in Amelius' book is not possible without a lot of fudging. Of course none of the Atlantis glyphs match and neither do the Destiny glyphs (which are not constellations). I think we can therefore assume that these glyphs represent constellations from Amelius' home galaxy.

With fudging, it's possible to draw connections to [Cetus](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Whale), [Aries](https://www.deviantart.com/eddieholly/art/RA-Stargate-185086687) or [Leo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205957) (your "styled hyphens"), [Aquila](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Aquila) or [Microscopium](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AM5XB5O), and [Cancer](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature18300) or [Sextans](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Johannes_Hevelius_und_Elisabetha_Hevelius.jpg) (or [Hydra](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/HYDRA) and [Norma](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51taEogaQOL._SY445_QL70_.jpg)) on the first line. But this is only 4 (or 5) symbols so it's unlikely that each line represents a unique address. And since several symbols would be duplicated between the two lines (notably the first and second symbols) it's unlikely that both lines represent a single address.

So what was Amelius doing when he wrote these symbols? [Well that's purely conjecture](http://elvortex.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/titan-ae.jpg).